# Regular expression from certain string

Tags: regex

I would like to know how to match a string with a regular expression for a certain length from a certain character or substring.

For example how do i match 5 characters back from the "tk" substring:

The string: "45gtyr eret dffg 45234tk ssdfr"

Should return: "45234".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a positive lookahead or capturing group.

```
.{5}(?=tk)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iD2iY0/1)

**OR**

```
(.{5})tk
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iD2iY0/2)

Comment: The first one does work great, the second one return "tk" as well as the 5 characters before it, But thank you very much! that helped me a lot :)

Comment: @RealGigex print the group index 1 in the second instead of index 0. Since you're new to stackoverflow, i suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)